# Saving draft emails whilst offline (Gmail App on Galaxy Note II)

Tags: gmail

I use the Gmail app on my Note II and it works well, but I have one problem that I experienced whilst in Flight mode.  I already had a partially drafted email in my Draft box and on the flight I edited the message and 'saved' it, only to find that when I opened it again the edited version was not there, only the orginal draft, so I lost everything that I had typed.  Is there a way to modify the settings so that edits to a draft are saved locally on the device?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [MailChimp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mailchimp.mailchimp)? I think it works even offline in iOS and Android phones.